# Notification is not working(Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, notifications

I am new to android studio. I was trying to create a notification when user click on a button embedded in recyclerView
user has to give time in Hours and Minutes only. I take user input as a string. And input is stored in SQLite database. 
notifyMeUpdate function is working fine but Toast in Receiver class is not shown(I think Receiver class is not triggered).

Please ignore typo
Here is my code:

```
class User{
    var id = 0
    var time = ""
    var amp = ""
    var text = ""
    var notifyMe = false
}
```

My User Class:

```
fun notifyMeUpdate(user: User) {
        alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager      
        var hour = 0
        var min  = 0
        for(i in 0 until user.time.length) {
            if (user.time[i] == ':'){
                var str = user.time.subSequence(0, i).toString()
                var minStr = user.time.subSequence(i+1, user.time.length).toString()
                if(user.amp == "AM"){
                    hour = str.toInt()
                    min = minStr.toInt()
                }
                else{
                    hour = str.toInt() + 12
                    min = minStr.toInt()
                }
            }
        }
        val cur_cal: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
        cur_cal.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val cal: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal[Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR])
        cal[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = hour
        cal[Calendar.MINUTE] = min
        cal[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
        cal[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = cur_cal[Calendar.MILLISECOND]
        cal[Calendar.DATE] = cur_cal[Calendar.DATE]
        cal[Calendar.MONTH] = cur_cal[Calendar.MONTH]
        val intent = Intent(context, Receiever::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
}
```

And here is my Receiever class

```
class Receiever: BroadcastReceiver(){
        lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager
        lateinit var notificationChannel: NotificationChannel
        lateinit var builder: Notification.Builder
        private var channelId = "package com.example.recyclerpractise"
        private var description = "Text Notification"
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Triggred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent =  Intent(context, LauncherActivity::class.java)
            val pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            if (context != null) {
                notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationChannel =
                    NotificationChannel(channelId, description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
                notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

                if (context != null) {
                    builder = Notification.Builder(context, channelId)
                        .setContentTitle("Hello Moto")
                        .setContentText("Test Notification")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
                        .setContentIntent(pintent)
                }
                else{
                    builder = Notification.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle("Hello Moto")
                        .setContentText("Test Notification")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context?.resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
                        .setContentIntent(pintent)
                }
                notificationManager.notify(19867, builder.build())
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my onBindViewHolder of recycler list

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val user: User = userList[p1]
        p0.time.text = user.time
        p0.text.text = user.text
        p0.img.setOnClickListener{
            val popup = PopupMenu(activity, p0.img)
            popup.inflate(R.menu.schedulemenu)
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener {

                when(it.itemId){
                    R.id.menu_delete->{
                        activity.dbHelper.deleteData(userList[p1].id.toLong())
                        activity.refreshList()
                    }
                    R.id.menu_update->{
                        activity.updateUser(userList[p1])
                    }
                    R.id.notify->{
                        activity.notifyMeUpdate(userList[p1])
                    }

                }
                true
            }
            popup.show()
        }
    }
```

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who tried. After several hours of debugging. I found that I did a very stupid mistake that haven't register my receiver in manifest file now it's working fine.